# Server keeps getting old result

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

After adding a user, the new user is not shown in the list. Everything works only after restarting the server. It looks like the server is downloading data from the cache memory. Maybe my code is not written properly. How to get current data from the database?

```js
// addFile

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("./db/dbSqlite/app.db", sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);

const add = (user) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    db.serialize(() => {
      let status = false;
      db.run(`INSERT INTO users(
        login,
        password,
        ) VALUES(?, ?)`, user, (err) => {
        if (err) rej(status);
        status = true;
        res(status);
      });
    })
  })
}
module.exports = add;

// getAll file

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("./db/dbSqlite/app.db");

const getAll = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  db.all(`SELECT * from users`, (err, row) => {
    if (row === undefined || err) {
      res("NO_TABLE_USERS");
    } else {
      const stringified = JSON.stringify(row)
      res(JSON.parse(stringified));
    }
  });
})

module.exports = getAll

// route

router.post("/add", helper.isLoggedIn, helper.isAdmin, (req, res) => {
  let msg = "User created successfully!";
  user.add(Object.values(req.body)
    .then((state) => {
      if (!state) msg = "Name already used!";
      user.getAll
        .then((result) => res.render("users", {
          name: req.user,
          users: result,
          msg: msg
        }));
    }));
});
```

Comment: I am assuming you are calling the getAll() after the add() returns the promise right?

Comment: `getAll` should be a function, otherwise it will be resolved once. Just like `add` in fact.

Comment: @js_noob Yes, u have this function above

Comment: Can you please confirm that you call `getAll.then` with `()` it should be like `getAll().then`. Please copy/paste the exact code without typos.

Comment: @Stamos Read the code. `getAll` is a `Promise` not a function, hence the `getAll.then`. There is no typo, the error is that `getAll` should be a function.

Comment: @Serge K. lol you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAll` should be a function, like you did with `add`. Otherwise, `getAll` will be resolved once :

```js
// addFile

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("./db/dbSqlite/app.db", sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);

const add = (user) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    db.serialize(() => {
      let status = false;
      db.run(`INSERT INTO users(
        login,
        password,
        ) VALUES(?, ?)`, user, (err) => {
        if (err) rej(status);
        status = true;
        res(status);
      });
    })
  })
}
module.exports = add;

// getAll file

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("./db/dbSqlite/app.db");

const getAll = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    db.all(`SELECT * from users`, (err, row) => {
      if (row === undefined || err) {
        res("NO_TABLE_USERS");
      } else {
        const stringified = JSON.stringify(row)
        res(JSON.parse(stringified));
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = getAll

// route

router.post("/add", helper.isLoggedIn, helper.isAdmin, (req, res) => {
  let msg = "User created successfully!";
  user.add(Object.values(req.body)
    .then((state) => {
      if (!state) msg = "Name already used!";
      user.getAll()
        .then((result) => res.render("users", {
          name: req.user,
          users: result,
          msg: msg
        }));
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you Serge. It seems to be working now! I've accepted your answer